# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "plink": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am executing a command in my `doPost()` method of `Servlet Class` which runs on Tomcat.

The command is :

```
plink -pw **** username@hostname tail -1000 /temp/info.txt
```

The command runs fine when I run it on my windows console but when executed inside servlet it throws this error.

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "plink": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

I tried executing the command through `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` as well as through

`ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("plink", "-pw", "***","username@hostname","tail","-1000","/temp/info.txt")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user's environment is typically not in effect when a program is run via certain intermediary actors since a shell's PATH is set in .bashrc, to be executed anew with each new shell.

So, a Java process, for instance, doesn't even run a shell, hence a search in PATH's directories isn't made.

Use full pathnames for programs run via Process on this and via remote execution services on another system.

Answer (score 0):

Need to give full path of plink, like this `C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe -pw **** username@hostname tail -1000 /temp/info.txt`